# STP on a bridge

Tags: bridge, stp

I have set up a bridge on an interface em1 and connected 4 vms to the bridge. I disabled stp on the bridge. There is no chance of looping as there is only one bridge in this setup, there occurs a BPDU error due to broadcast storming in my switch. Will a bridge forward packets on the source port also if STP is disabled or is there any other reason for this broadcast storm?

Comment: What if two network interfaces are set up on one of your VMs and bridging is enabled? ---> loop!

Comment: "em1" is this xen with a BSD dom0? Knowing what virtualization environment is involved really helps with the details since implementations differ wildly in their behaviour.

Comment: My seup: I created lxc containers on a centos 6 host machine. em1 of host machine and eth0 of containers are connected to linux bridge